# How to start and coordinate flow tasks in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have a CI task in Jenkins that polls scm and builds my projects. Also there are  several Autotests tasks:

- Autotests project A
- Autotests project B
- Autotests project C

C depends on B which depends on A.

So, I want CI task to call Autotests A -> B -> C. But A task mustn't start again before C if finished. Suppose, during execution of A, B, C CI task was executed 3 times (as a result of 3 pushes to scm). In this case Autotests flow must be started only once for all three pushes.

How can I setup this with Jenkins? I use trigger plugin but it starts downstream tasks A, B, C each time (even previous Autotests flow hasn't finised), which is not desirable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the project's advanced configuration are two options:

- Block build when upstream project is building
- Block build when downstream project is building

For project C, if you block its build while upstream projects are running, it won't run until A and B are done.

For project A, if you block its build while downstream projects are running, it will wait for B and C to finish before it runs.

Answer (score 0):

Set the "Restrict where this job can be run" check box in your job A configuration and specify the name of your slave.

Then check the radio flag called 'Throttle concurrent builds' ( You will need https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Throttle+Concurrent+Builds+Plugin to do that ) And set overall and per node maximum builds to 1.

This will ensure that only one instance of job A will run at the given moment of time. The rest of the triggered jobs A will remain in queue and start only after the previous are completed.